# how to put html into else

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I have a problem with the below code. How do I put html code into `//do nothing;`'s place?

```
<?php 
  $matnmusic = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'matnmusic', true);
  if ($matnmusic) { ?>
<p><h3><div class="matn-ms" style="text-align: center ; color: #400361 "> <? echo $matnmusic; ?></h3></p>
<?php 
  } else { 
     // do nothing;
  }
?>
```

I have tried as below, but this code gives an error:

```
<?php 
  $matnmusic = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'matnmusic', true);
  if ($matnmusic) { ?>
<p><h3><div class="matn-ms" style="text-align: center ; color: #400361 "> <? echo $matnmusic; ?></h3></p>
<?php 
  } else { 
<center><span id="button"><a title="lyrics" href="/send-lyric/" style="color:#FFF;">lyrics</a></span></center>
  }
?>
```

Comment: Just do exactly the same as you did for "if": `<?php } else { ?>HTML...<?php } ?>`

Comment: thanks @paulsm4 , But I couldn't

Comment: You can't just dump HTML code into PHP. Close the PHP tag, put your HTML and then reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with your code and it also didn't work. But I made some changes and now it should work because it is working for me. Since you added `style=color:#FFF;` in `<a>` tag the result is not showing because the background is also white. And also instead of `<? echo $matnmusic; ?>`, use `<?= $matnmusic; ?>` or `<?php echo $matnmusic; ?>`. Now it should work in case if there is a problem with the following statement.

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'matnmusic', true);
```

So you can just try that if your HTML is working or not by removing the above statement and add `$matnmusic = false or true`. Then it will work. Hope this helps you.

```
<?php 

$matnmusic = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'matnmusic', true);

if ($matnmusic) { ?>

<p>
    <h3>
        <div class="matn-ms" style="text-align:center; color: #400361;"> 
            <?= $matnmusic; ?>
    </h3>
</p>

<?php } else { ?>

<center>
    <span id="button">
        <a title="lyrics" href="/send-lyric/" style="color:red;">lyrics</a>
    </span>
</center>

<?php } ?>
```